# Which listener can know that the JTextPane value is changed?

Tags: java, swing, events, jtextpane

I would like to know when `JTextPane` content is changed.  I implemented a keyboard listener, but it is only detecting keyboard events.  If the user pastes text via mouse or drag the text inside, then I am not enable to detect the `JTextPane` value is changed.  Which event listener can tell me that the `JTextPane` value is changed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you have to look for [DocumentListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)